# Permissions error when running command on nats-box in cluster

Tags: nats.io

I'm using the nats-box deployed to a local cluster, to check the status of the nats server thats running in the same cluster.

When running nats server commands in the shell of the nats-box I'm getting permissions errors.

> nats: error: no results received, ensure the account used has system privileges and appropriate permissions

I've seen this error before and it was something to do with the path where the command is executed from. Are there any additional steps needed to get the nats-box container able to run nats server commands?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send a command that requires a user in the $SYS account, but the user that you are using is not for that account.
Define a system account with some user(s) in your NATS server.conf file:

```
accounts: {
  $SYS: {
    users: [ 
        {user:syso, password:pwd}
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can create a context in nats-cli to use it, or directly provide the details in the command line:

```
nats --user=syso  --password=pwd ...
```

Comment: BTW, put it at most outer level of config file.